# Xcode copy-paste breakpoints

Tags: xcode, debugging, development-environment

Is there any way to copy-paste breakpoints in Xcode?

The reason I am asking is, I have a breakpoint set to "**automatically continue after evaluating**", with some actions associated. I want to have the same breakpoint behavior/action in multiple places in the code. Instead of re-doing it (Setting breakpoint, customizing it) 10 times (or even more which can be cumbersome), just copy-paste it!?

Comment: your question prompted me to do yet antother google search session for this topic, which yet again came up dry. Im beginning to believe that its not possible. Im gonna file a feature request for this when i find the time...

Comment: unbelievable how after this much time we still don't have such a basic feature. copy and paste was in the first version of Mac OS!

Answer (score 7):

I've found a solution, though it might not be easier. All of the breakpoints are saved in an XML file inside your Xcode project. To find the file, select your project file and choose "Show Package Contents", then go to:

`xcuserdata/(YourNameHere).xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/`

You can open the breakpoints file and copy /paste their XML. You can then change the file and line numbers of the breakpoints.

Comment: Set the breakpoints first, then find that file - you'll save yourself having to type in the line numbers and file names. But in XC7, I can't find the xcdebugger file in xcuserdatad :(

Comment: it is not working, Xcode overwrites the file, deleting the changes I did :(

Answer (score 1):

In the scope of one file, you can easily duplicate breakpoints from Breakpoints Navigator (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>). Just select a particular breakpoint and then copy and paste (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>).

It's going to be duplicated on the same line, so you need to move it with mouse to any other line.

Unfortunately, it's not currently possible to move breakpoints between files (Xcode 13.1).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well as I wanted to share some of my more elaborate breakpoints with people in my team.

#### Project with CocoaPods

You will find the *xcdebugger* directory in

```
PROJECT_NAME.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/xcdebugger
```

Second, you will need to make the breakpoint a shared breakpoint by right clicking the breakpoint and clicking **Share Breakpoint**

[image]

You should then find the *Breakpoints_vX.xcbkptlist* file with your shared breakpoints in the *xcdebugger*

#### Project with no CocoaPods

You should find the *xcdebugger* directory **for the shared breakpoints** here

```
PROJECT_NAME.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcdebugger
```

In there you will find the same breakpoints file you seek. There is also a xcdebugger directory in the *xcuserdata/USERNAME.xcuserdatad* but they might have some coded file paths that would be problematic when sharing other devices.